# Múltiples permisos de usuarios PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sesiones

intento hacer un login con tres tipos de usuarios: Admin, Consulta y Estudiante. Hice la validación de estos tres, pero quisiera saber cómo validar a un usuario que tenga permisos de Consulta y de Estudiante al mismo tiempo.
Esta es mi consulta:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN u_p on usuarios.usuario_id=u_p.usuario_id WHERE usuarios.correo ='".$usuario."'") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Y aquí hago la validación:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row['contrasena'] ==  $contrasena)
{

        if($row['perfil_id'] ==  1)
        {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['correo'] = $usuario;
            header("Location: admin.php");

        }

        else if ($row['perfil_id'] == 2)
        { 
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['correo'] = $usuario;
                header("Location: consulta.php");

        }

        else if ($row['perfil_id'] == 3)
        {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['correo'] = $usuario;
                header("Location: estudiante.php");

        }}}
```

O si existe alguna otra manera de hacer la validación, gracias de antemano

Estructura de las tablas:

```
`CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `usuario_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_u` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ap_p` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ap_m` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `dep_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_i` date NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `contrasena` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `perfiles_usuario` (
  `perfil_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `perfil` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `u_p` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `perfil_id` int(10) NOT NULL
)`
```

Comment: El como es relativamente fácil,  ¿Pero porque querrías eso? Quiero decir, con el código que muestras un usuario con permisos de consulta y estudiante a que página debería de ser dirigido?  Y luego a nivel de base de datos, como creo que tienes estructurada la tabla un usuario con dos permisos daría como resultado dos filas no? Normalmente los permisos van en aumento para solucionar estas cosas, de tal forma que un admin puede hacer lo que consulta y estudiante, estudiante lo de consulta y consulta solo consulta por poner un ejemplo. Dale una vuelta a ver que quieres y te ayudamos encantados!

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Bienvenido. Para agregar las tablas borra los comentarios y pega el código en tu pregunta. Puedes darle al boton editar bajo tu pregunta para agregar contenido. Un saludo!.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que un usuario tenga varios permisos, ¿debería cambiar mi estructura de las tablas?

Comment: Te sugiero agregar o tener campos para cada permiso como; insertar, actualizar, consultar, etc.. donde este campo seria tipo Integer(1-0) donde 1 equivale a que si posee X ó Y permiso, al hacer el login tambien podrias agregar al $_SESSION el listado de los permisos que posee y en tu(template) vista verificas si tiene o no el respectivo permiso.